# How to make autotest only run integration tests when I press ^C

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autotest

Is there any hook in autotest that could make it work like this: skip running the integration tests (as they are slow), unless I press `^C` to run all of them?

As an added bonus, if I modify a specific integration test, it should be run by autotest normally.

Comment: Must it be CTRL+C? That normally sends `SIGINT` which instructs the process to *stop* running.

Comment: Andrew, yes, but this question is specifically about the autotest tool, which uses CTRL+C for different purpose, i.e. to re-run the whole suite. If you don't know about autotest, see https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest or http://ph7spot.com/musings/getting-started-with-autotest.

Answer (score 1):

A month passed and no answers, so I'll just post how I temporary solved the problem. **Any real solutions still appreciated.**

For now, I'm running autotest with like this:

```
autotest -w -f -c
```

These options mean:

```
-f, --fast-start                 Do not run full tests at start
-c, --no-full-after-failed       Do not run all tests on red->green
-w, --warnings                   Turn on ruby warnings
```

So, whenever I touch any file, `autotest` runs the tests for it and when something breaks, it keeps running the test until it's fixed, but then there's no full test run after that. When I feel ready to run the full suite (e.g. before committing), I press `^C` for that (the full suite takes ~8 minutes to pass).

That works for me, but it's not perfect. I'd prefer not to use `-c` option and have the full suite (but **without integration tests**) run on red->green. Integration tests should be included only when I press `^C` (or any other way if possible, but only when I want it).

Any thoughts?